# Calabash Android: Is it possible, in a feature file, to call certain previous lines of the same feature file (re-use previous steps)?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing, calabash

Is it possible, in a `feature file`, to call certain previous lines of the same `feature file`?

Comment: What about calling an entire feature file from within another one.

Answer (score 2):

Without using some steps of same feature file again you can use combined steps.

Ex :

Think you need to delete an order and go to home screen several times in a same feature file and for that think you need to call this 4 lines

```
      Then I touch order cart delete order button
      Then I should see delete item alert in oder cart and select YES option
      Then I wait for 1 seconds
      Then I go to home screen
```

So you need to call this 4 lines in 4 times in the same file. Instead of that you can define a new step in a ruby file like this

```
Then /^I delete order from ordercart$/ do
  steps %{
      Then I touch order cart delete order button
      Then I should see delete item alert in oder cart and select YES option
      Then I wait for 1 seconds
      Then I go to home screen
}
end
```

And now you can directly delete an order using single line calling in feature file

```
Then I delete order from ordercart
```

Now you need only 4 lines instead of 16 lines and also it is easy to maintain the new changes to the code when you need in the future.

Answer (score 1):

check out the 'step' command in cucumber.

In my experience though, it's a better practice to use conventional ruby method definitions and and call those from your step definitions. Steps calling other steps can get really messy.